Why chromedriver is found when running symfony command, and not found when doing http request?
I have app running on Docker. It has nginx and php containers. Chrome client is installed on php container for crawling purposes.
I have a service that fetches content of an url.
$this->client = Client::createChromeClient();
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url);  

When calling service method from Symfony Command - this works, content is fetched.
When I do post request and call the service method from a Controller I get
"chromedriver" binary not found. Install it using the package manager of your operating system or by running "composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/bin/bdi detect drivers". error.
Why is that?
I am expecting chrome client to be working in both cases.

can you please check the location of chrome driver with following command in docker whcih docker exec -it <php_container_name> which chromedriver

It is returning 2 lines:
/usr/bin/docker
/usr/bin/which

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
wget gnupg2 apt-transport-https curl 
&& wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - 
&& echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list 
&& apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable chromium-chromedriver 
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
add this in your PHP docker file
